# Print using Brother QL-800 printer with raspberry pi

Tags: python, printing, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to use raspberry pi to print from a python code.

I tried using the brother-ql module but it doesn't give me an error.
However, the printer doesn't print anything.

This a snapshot of my code and the result it gives.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R5nJ.png)

Is there any suggestion?
I have posted the coding in the image

Comment: I have had a few examples with a Brother printer and it has not proven to be the best option, i suggest a zebra printer. if you already have to use brother, then print via CUPS briefly os.system("lp - printer document") etc..

Comment: I tried but it just doesn't print but I managed to figure it out. Thanks anyway !

Comment: it is better to provide the code here and the error message instead of serving an image. Would be great if you edit and update your post

Comment: Please use proper code format like this `code` and avoid using image to serve code and debugging details. Use image to show non-console output resultst only.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to print with the Brother QL-800 printer with Raspberry Pi.

I used the cups module in python to print.

```
import cups

conn = cups.Connection()

printers = conn.getPrinters()

printer_name = (printers.keys())[0]

#desired location of file to read

conn.printFile(printer_name, '/home/pi/Desktop/whatsup.csv',"",{})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Even though the previous answer is correct, it prompts an 'object is not subscriptable' error in Python 3. The following fix is tested with added printing features... printer_name is a list.

```
import cups

conn = cups.Connection()
printers = conn.getPrinters()
printer_name = list(printers.keys())[0]

conn.printFile(printer_name,'file.txt','',{'landscape':'True', 'cpi':'14', 'lpi':'10'}) #the smaller cpi/lpi the bigger the fonts
```